# What is the default connection timeout for Perforce?

Tags: perforce

I am connecting through the `P4Perl` Api to a `Perforce` server and I wanted to know if the connection operation is aborted after a set period of time or I have to treat it from my `Perl` code.

```
use P4;
my $perforceObject = new P4;

$perforceObject->SetPort( 'test-1234:8080');
$perforceObject->SetUser( 'user1234');

# try to connect for 10s or abort unless the connection is aborted automatically
$perforceObject->Connect();
```

Comment: "the connection is aborted"? What does this mean?

Comment: @BryanPendleton It means that it will stop trying to connect if it didn't succed until then (not a native speaker) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know Perforce doesn't have its own built-in timeout and depends instead on the OS's TCP/IP implementation.  I'm pretty sure most systems will fail the initial connection before 10 seconds have elapsed so you should be fine without having to add your own kill switch.